# Redrawing a GtkDrawingArea after editing a tree cell

Tags: c, gtk3

I'm writing a program that prints bank deposit slips. The UI includes a `GtkDrawingArea` preview of the deposit slip. As a user enters amounts to be deposited, the preview updates with the new/modified amount and total amount deposited.

What signal-callback combination do I use to redraw the preview?

My current implementation uses two signal-callback combinations. The first signal-callback is on a cell containing a deposit amount. When the signal "edited" is fired, the callback `deposit_amount_edited` runs.

```c
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(rendererChecks), "edited", G_CALLBACK(deposit_amount_edited), pointer_passer);
```

Within the callback `draw_background` I emit a draw signal on the drawing area.

```c
void deposit_amount_edited(GtkCellRendererText *self,
                     gchar *path,
                     gchar *new_text,
                     gpointer data) {
  
    GHashTable *pointer_passer = (GHashTable *)data; /* Hash table containing all sorts of pointers */

    /* Retrieve the pointer to the GtkDrawingArea */
    GtkDrawingArea *drawing_area = (GtkDrawingArea *)g_hash_table_lookup(pointer_passer, &KEY_DRAWING_AREA);
  
    g_signal_emit_by_name(drawing_area, "draw", data); /*Seg fault */
}
```

I get a segmentation fault on `g_signal_emit_by_name`.

- Why is that?
- More importantly, what is the best way to redraw the preview after editing a cell in a `GtkTreeView`?

Comment: Is our app open source? Your bank deposit slip sounds interesting and useful to my own app [PyGtk Posting](https://github.com/benreu/PyGtk-Posting).

Comment: @theGtknerd Yes, it is very much open source and very much an amateur's project. See https://github.com/5dma/deposit_slips . Comments are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have an answer to my first question, I do have an answer to the second. In my above function `deposit_amount_edited` I replaced `g_signal_emit_by_name` with  `gtk_widget_queue_draw(GTK_WIDGET(drawing_area));` That draws the preview correctly.